# PySide Qt Creator message dialog exit

Tags: python, qt-creator, pyside

So I created a ui file with Qt Creator that has, among other things, a QPushButton. Just for testing purposes I want to pop up a QMessageDialog that says hello! After opening the ui in the main window class, I connect the button from the ui to the def hello(self):

```
myWidget.helloButton.clicked.connect(self.hello)
```

then later on

```
def hello(self):
    QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self,'Message',"hello!",QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok)
```

The message pops up saying "hello!" and after I click "ok" inside the message dialog, the entire python program exits, effectively crashing the main window GUI

This did not happen to me when I was not using the UI file. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

edit: This happens as soon as I click "ok"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\George\Desktop\loadui..py", line 25, in <module>
main()
File "C:\Users\George\Desktop\loadui..py", line 23, in main
sys.exit(app.exec_())
SystemExit: 0
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? Is there any error message displayed?

Comment: OK… Can you post your `main`, then ? So that we can try to give you a proper explanation...

Comment: I figured it out thanks, I changed the UI to a wdiget and then had then in main had a QMainWindow and used setCentralWidget

Comment: So, where was the problem? `app.exec_()` was returning 0, right ? Putting a `sys.exit` around was probably not the best idea, as it tells Python to exit, don't you think?

Comment: All of the tutorials on pyside have it and I haven't experienced any issues prior

Answer (score 0):

Changing the parent of the `QDialog` from `self` to `QtGui.QApplication.activeWindow()` worked for me.